# Insert arrays into database

Tags: php, arrays, lumen

[image: output]

So this is the output I get after submitting my form. Now I need to insert them into the database. The "sun","mon".. key are static and so is the "start",'end' key too.

So I have done the following for all the days. I know that it is not efficient. Is there a better way?

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    //dump(['start'=> $data['sun'][$i]['start'],'end'=> $data['sun'][$i]['end']);
    $this->routineModel->create([
        'start'=> $data['sun'][$i]['start'],
        'end'=> $data['sun'][$i]['end'],
        'group_id' => $data['group_id'],
        'day_id' => 1,
        'schedule_id' => $data['schedule_id']
    ]);
}
```

This is my database:
[image: database]

This is my HTML form:

```
<label>Sunday:</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>From:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sun[0][start]" type="date">
    <label>To:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sun[0][end]" type="date">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>From:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sun[1][start]" type="date">
    <label>To:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sun[1][end]" type="date">
</div>
```

And I am using the `lumen` framework.

Comment: you could create an array with the days, then loop over that array, with your current array nested in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

you may use serialization to save whole array

Answer (score 0):

```
$serialized_array=serialize($your_array);
```

And directly save it in the database.

While fetching the rows use **unserialize** to get array back

Hope this helps.